How can I do a code in one line, that processes random data?
You measure the time dependence of a certain value 10 times by selecting 100 time values, as a result you get an array of 10x100. Simulate it with random values:
arr = np.random.random((100, 10))

Measurements for which significant noise is observed over time are considered bad. For each of the 10 measurements, consider the noise significant if the standard deviation for this time dependence is 1.25 times greater than the standard deviation for all 10 dependencies. For such time dependencies, reduce the noise by reducing by 1.5 times the values that deviate from the average value by more than 0.25.
Do all these actions in one line of code
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((100,10))
arr[np.std(arr, axis=0) > np.std(arr).mean() * 1.25] = np.where(np.abs(arr - np.mean(arr, axis=0)) > 0.25, arr / 1.5, arr)

This is not working

it says ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (100,10) (100,10)

Please use the right formatting for your questions. Without code blocks this was near unreadable. Also, never just indicate that "it is not working", explain what the expected outcome is as well as the actual reasult (and any note of things that you've tried).

You can try adding semicolon ; after each individual line -
import numpy as np; arr = np.random.random((100,10)); ...   and so one when adding to one line

The question is not clear of what is not working, but the single line is the last line (see the updated edit of the question). So this should not be the issue.  Note that the org question did have these three lines on separate lines, but this was not shown due to how MarkDown operates.
